# Laravel : How to hide the interpolation code before Vue js loads?

Tags: javascript, php, vuejs2

I have a Laravel website, when I use Laravel to load my data from the database, then a pass the results to JavaScript this way

```
<script>
window.forfaits = <?php echo json_encode($results); ?>;
</script>
```

Then I use Vue js `v-for` to display my data.
The problem is that I see interpolation on the home page before Vue Js loads and v-cloak can't do the work since I'm getting my data with php then pass to js.

How can I do so that interpolation doesn't show on the page?

**UPDATE**

By interpolation I mean this:

[image]

And here is my main.blade.php file which is loaded as the home page:

```
<script>
window.forfaits = <?php echo json_encode($forfaits); ?>;
</script>
@extends('layouts.app')

<div>
@section('main-content')
<div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9">
    <div id="filter-items">
        <div class="product-item offre" v-for="forfait in filteredForfaits">
            <div class="product-na">
                <h3 class="product-name">@{{forfait.nom_forfait}}</h3>
                <div class="product-actions">
                 ............................
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'interpolation'?

Comment: Also, please post your Vue template.

Comment: Why not add a body class that hides everything and then remove that body class on load with JavaScript? You could even add a transition it to make it look like the page fades in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're trying to use `v-cloak` to hide uncompiled templates you should create CSS rule as described here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-cloak

It works really simple. Uncompiled templates is hidden by `v-cloak` css rule. If Vue compiler seeing `v-cloak` attribute on the compiled template, it simply deletes the attribute and your component appears on the page.

```
[v-cloak] {
  display: none;
}
```

Have you include it?

Also, you must be sure that css file, contains [v-cloak] rule will be loaded at a time the uncompiled Vue templates appears. You should decide critical css or use `rel="preload"` (already available in modern browsers) for that piece of css.

Comment: Yes, i have included v-cloak, but since the page is rendered with Laravel blade, i have the code showing on the screen because Vue js not loaded yet

Comment: @NacimIdjakirene You're not required to have already loaded Vue to use v-cloak attribute. Firstly, template is compiled by Vue, then v-cloak attribute is removed by Vue if it present. Try it: ```<h3 class="product-name" v-cloak>@{{forfait.nom_forfait}}</h3>```

Comment: Just tried it and it does't work, before Vue js can compile the template it have to load, and before that blad is rendering the template and ignore the @{{CODE}} so it sohw on the browser.

Comment: @NacimIdjakirene is CSS with ```[v-cloak]``` rule loaded in this moment?

Comment: OMG ! i think its working ! let me just test it on production

Comment: it chrome it works fine, but in firefox css take a litle more type than chrom to load, so i see the html before css load. any idea how to fix ?

Comment: @NacimIdjakirene yeah, it's always a problem. Try to read something about critical css. Also, modern browsers allow us to preload some css with ```rel="preload"```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, are you loading Vue from the bottom of your HTML code?
if you do maybe you should put it inside your head tag so it could be loaded earlier.

But, my advice for you is to build your whole app thourgh Vue, i can see that you're building a panel of something?
Maybe you should consider building everything with Vue and get the data with an API endpoint that Laravel will provide you, that's how I'd build it.

Comment: I think its exaclty what im going to do, but any hack to hide this from the screen tomporary ?

Comment: maybe you can implement a loader on top of your site that will hide everything behind, when the vue js file is loaded you can hide the loader and you will see everything as you expect.